# Source of img: "/images/..." vs "images/..." in PHP websites (VSCode and XAMPP)

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, xampp, xdebug

I have recently been drafting a website in HTML and CSS, but since the scope of the site is larger than originally planned I want to use PHP as well (for e.g. shared nav menus). After getting my server set up (VSCode, PHP w/ Xdebug, XAMPP) I simply changed my `index.html` to `index.php` and previewed the page.

The website was identical except *some* images were broken. I noticed the ones that worked were sourced as `images/...` and there ones that were broken were sourced as `/images/...`.

Is there a difference between **/images/** and **images/**?

---

Some extra information that may play into this: When setting up PHP it was a fresh install of XAMPP and using the PHP debug with Xdebug extension in VSCode. When debugging and launching the server to preview my website I kept getting the XAMPP dashboard even though my website source was set as `"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"`. The only way I could bypass this was for the project to set it absolutely by removing `webroot` and replacing it with `"url": "http://localhost:8080/WebsiteDirectory/"`.

Comment: Lets assume that the current URL is `domain.test/path/page.php` and you use both ways to reference the same image (e.g. `logo.png`). In first case (absolute) the actual URL for that would be `domain.test/images/logo.png` and in 2nd one it is relative to the current URL... so it's `domain.test/path/images/logo.png`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

**/images/** is an absolute path starting from the root of your page

**images/** is relative from subfolder you're in.

And actually it's HTML question, not PHP.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but the problem is how root is defined in my php server implementation for test,  no? Whatever funny business is happening with vscode / php debug I can't set my web root correctly (it just goes to xampp dash). All my images will be in /images/ (root of the web directory).

Comment: `/images/ == **root of the website**